# Close as duplicate dialog: Accepted, highest-voted answer not shown

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, close-dialog

I voted to close a question as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051012/should-i-return-const-objects). After entering the URL, the close dialog displays the question and its answers. In this dialog, I could only see 10 of the 12 answers (one of the 10 having been deleted), and those did not include the accepted answer, which is also the highest-voted answer.

This behavior could lead other potential voters to believe that the question did not have a good answer, and thus not vote to close.

This happens because the question has a large number of answers. It seems like the dialog only shows the ten oldest answers, sorted by votes. Instead, it should show the ten highest-voted answers.

Comment: Works that way for me as well.

Comment: looking into it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in build rev 2013.7.9.824